# Returning a Status from the Domain

Tags: domain-driven-design

In our domain-driven application, we use a type called `ServiceResponse<>` to send data between layers of our application - specifically, one is returned by every method in the domain. As of right now, it encapsulates the data (if any) which was returned from the method, or any errors that it may have generated.

My question, then, is this: is it an acceptable practice to add fields to this object that may be useful in other layers of the application? For example, is it good form to add a `Status` or `StatusCode` field to it that may be interpreted later by the service layer for use as an HTTP status code (with or without some mapping)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a fine place to me. The idea that every method returns a "response" of some sort smells a bit like trying to decouple too much, but there are some cases where such extreme decoupling is warranted.

In any case, the `ServiceResponse` could easily have a status, and if it needed one, that is where I would put it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing is, though, this status code would probably be mostly (if not solely) for the service layer. So is that a good thing: for the Domain layer to cater specifically to the service layer?

Comment: No, the domain layer shouldn't have a care in the world about what layers above it do with it's members. The `ServiceResponse<>` should itself be a resident in the service layer and would _contain_ the relevant domain objects when the service methods return. Domain objects should only have methods that know about other domain objects - Nothing more.